# What are these black streaks in ParametricPlot3D and how to get rid of them

Tags: plotting

Trying to reimplement [certain graph](http://tmajlath.byethost13.com/plotVXY.gif) I am doing

```
ParametricPlot3D[Append[ReIm[Zeta[s+I t]],t],{s,.1,.9},{t,.5,35},
    Mesh->None,ColorFunction->(Hue[(#4-.1)/.8]&),BoxRatios->{1, 1, 1},MaxRecursion->5]
```

and get

[image]

What causes this dirt? How to clean it up?

Comment: Might just not be enough plot points. `PlotPoints -> 200` seems to fix it for me.

Comment: Maybe [Nyan Cat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4) ate anything unhealthy... ;)

Comment: @MassDefect Thanks for the suggestion, but some blots are still there, and moreover it becomes too heavy to rotate it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher So you suggest a laxative?

Comment: Erm. No, I sort of meant the opposite...

Comment: MassDefect had the right idea, but a little finesse is necessary: `ParametricPlot3D[Append[ReIm[Zeta[s + I t]], t], {s, 1/10, 9/10}, {t, 1/2, 35}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[(#4 - 0.1)/0.8] &), Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {45, 105}]`

Comment: @J.M. Wow this is WAY better! Would you like to move this to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, one must consider relative ranges of the independent variables when setting `PlotPoints`. Here, the `t` variable spans a vastly wider range than the `s` variable, so one must supply a higher `PlotPoints` setting corresponding to the former.

In particular,

```
ParametricPlot3D[Append[ReIm[Zeta[s + I t]], t], {s, 1/10, 9/10}, {t, 1/2, 35}, 
                 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[(#4 - 0.1)/0.8] &),
                 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {65, 125}]
```

[image: 3D zeta spiral]

Comment: Seems like `PlotPoints -> {10,300}` is even better - I don't think such thing would be machine- or version-specific, right?

Comment: It shouldn't be. As long as the general idea of "use more points for larger parameter ranges" applies.

Comment: Right, and $65 < 125$, and $10<300$. ;)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: rescale the z-axis (so that the three axes have similar ranges) and

1. change the vertical axis labels using `` Charting`FindTicks ``:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Append[ReIm[Zeta[s + I t]], Rescale[t, {1/2, 35}, {0, 5}]], 
  {s, 1/10, 9/10}, {t, 1/2, 35}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[(#4 - 0.1)/0.8] &), Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, 5}, {1/2, 35}]}]
```

[image]

2. or use the option `ScalingFunctions`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Append[ReIm[Zeta[s + I t]], Rescale[t, {1/2, 35}, {0, 5}]], 
     {s, 1/10, 9/10}, {t, 1/2, 35}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[(#4 - 0.1)/0.8] &), Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", 
     {Rescale[#, {0, 5}, {1/2, 35}] &, Rescale[#, {1/2, 35}, {0, 5}] &}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Strangely, in my Mathematica 11 the words `ScalingFunctions` and `"Linear"` are red, although rendering goes without errors.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, I also get the same highlighting (version 11.3 Windows 10 ).

Comment: Wish I could accept yours too. I chose the other one only because it looks simpler.